# How to update "Production" deployment using Code Push CLI?

Tags: react-native, code-push

I've been showing my team my progress with the `Staging` key.
 When I do `code-push deployment ls APP_NAME_HERE -k`,
it'll give me a `Staging` and `Production` table with `Production` having the message `No updates released`.

I have been using `code-push release-react APP_NAME_HERE ios` to update.
Can anyone guide me as to what options I need to send to `Production` instead of `Staging`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use --deploymentName to specify the deployment you want to update.

`code-push release-react APP_NAME_HERE ios --deploymentName Production`

You could also promote your release from staging to production ([docs](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/cli.html#link-9)):

`code-push promote APP_NAME_HERE Staging Production`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the key I set in my info.plist file in xcode have to be the staging key then? What should the value of that key be, staging or production?

Comment: You should create a separate Info-Staging.plist and use that for staging and put the production key into Info.plist. You could also put a placeholder $(CODE_PUSH_KEY) into Info.plist and replace it during the build with an environment variable defined in the scheme.

Comment: so if I want to have a two versions, one for testing one for production I need to build and release two packages, in case of Android it will be an apk file so it's easy to share what should I do for IOS? submit both to Apple store?

Comment: @demsey ever find an answer to this question? Should the staging app be a separate app?

Comment: no I didn't, for IOS I have only production app, for Android both test and production