# Is there a difference between the staging and production env in code push?

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

I accidentally push the binary with staging key. Is there any real difference between the two stages(in terms of cli / library setting) aside from the obvious naming differences ?

Will I have problem trying to push updates using the staging env?

Answer (score 5):

Code push `Staging` deployments are for debug builds (app-debug.apk)s while `Production` is as you guess, production releases (app-release.apk)s.

Refer to this text on their README [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#multi-deployment-testing),  Saying:

> And that's it! Now when you run or build your app, your debug builds will automatically be configured to sync with your Staging deployment, and your release builds will be configured to sync with your Production deployment.

In your case I think you won't have any problems pushing updates with staging env as it a feature but they will be limited to `app-debug.apk`s and not `app-release.apk` ones.

I would guess you wrote something like

`code-push release-react <appName> <platform>`

Then it said something like this

> Upload progress:[==================================================]
>   100% 0.0s Successfully released an update containing the
>   "/tmp/CodePush" directory to the "Staging" deployment of the
>   "APP_NAME" app.

This is staging and should be used to test your app in the devices you installed the `app-debug.apk` bundle so you know how your update is going to work.

If you are okay with it, then you should promote it to the Production builds with

`code-push promote APP_NAME_HERE Staging Production`

Or Follow this answer here: [How to update "Production" deployment using Code Push CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616715/how-to-update-production-deployment-using-code-push-cli)
 to just release an update straight to production builds.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Is there any real difference between the two stages(in terms of cli /
>   library setting) aside from the obvious naming differences

I can say - no, there is no difference and its up to you to decide how to build your workflow (although there are some practices in terms of how you can use it e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#multi-deployment-testing).

The difference between two of this is more on semantically level and how you will use it depends upon you.

Moreover you can create arbitrary number of deployments if having a staging and production version of your app is enough to meet your needs. 
You can use `code-push deployment add <appName> <deploymentName>` for this.
Also you can rename/delete deployments if it is needed.